# Wordpress menu has wrong anchor links

Tags: wordpress

I have the following problem and no clue whats happening:

I'm working on a wordpress page:

http://ordnung3126.apps-1and1.net/

And I noticed that in Chrome the anchor links of the menue don't work however in Edge for example they do just fine.
The links to other pages e.g. "Impressum" or "Referenzen" do work and if you're currently on one of these the anchor links to the main page work fine too.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache?

Comment: Yes, but it didn’t help...

Comment: Does this happened to all browsers or just chrome browser?

Comment: Till now I just tried it in chrome and edge, I do not know if the same behavior shows in Firefox, Opera etc. In safari on iOS it works fine :/

Comment: its actually working on my chrome browser. Now, try it on your chrome browser but in incognito mode. to open incognito mode, open chrome and press ctrl+shift+n, then paste the url.

Comment: I'm suspecting the problem is in your chrome browser. try clearing the your browser cache.

Comment: it's still not working. i suspect it's a problem with my browser, but I have no guarantee that it's working at other people's browsers...

Comment: its working on my browser. You need to check on other browser as well and see if its working.

Comment: I tried it in other browsers and it works on every browser but chrome and I am wondering why...